# Multi patterend varadic templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I don't think this is possible based on what I've read however I'm hoping someone here may know of some solution that would get this to work.

I have a vector (maths) class for C++

```
template <typename T, size_t N> class vec;
```

And want to create a varadic `friend` function apply to apply a function to these vectors element-wise

i.e.

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args> friend vec<typename std::result_of<pow(Args&&...)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const vec<Args, N>&... args);
```

which is valid (untested yet)

however I want to achieve a pattern like

```
template <typename F> friend vec<typename std::result_of<F&&(T&&)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const vec<T, N>& V);
template <typename F> friend vec<typename std::result_of<F&&(T&&, T&&)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const vec<T, N>& V1, const vec<T, N>& V2);
template <typename F> friend vec<typename std::result_of<F&&(T&&, T&&)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const vec<T, N>& V1, const T& V2);
template <typename F> friend vec<typename std::result_of<F&&(T&&, T&&)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const T& V1, const vec<T, N>& V2);
template <typename F, typename U> friend vec<typename std::result_of<F&&(T&&, U&&)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const vec<T, N>& V1, const vec<U, N>& V2);
template <typename F, typename U> friend vec<typename std::result_of<F&&(T&&, U&&)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const vec<T, N>& V1, const U& V2);
template <typename F, typename U> friend vec<typename std::result_of<F&&(U&&, T&&)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const vec<U, N>& V1, const vec<T, N>& V2);
template <typename F, typename U> friend vec<typename std::result_of<F&&(U&&, T&&)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const U& V1, const vec<T, N>& V2);
```

note that only one of the arguments is required to be a vector any scalars would be broadcasted to the length of the vector.

The idea is that `apply(pow, /*vec<float,N>*/V, /*int*/n) -> {pow(V.v[i],n)...}` where `i -> 0 ... N` rather than `apply(pow, /*vec<float,N>*/V, /*int*/n) -> apply(pow, /*vec<float,N>*/V, /*vec<int,N>*/tmp{/*int*/n}) {pow(V.v[i],tmp.v[i])...}`

So I would like to be able to write something like the following (which isn't valid C++, but it should give an idea of what I want to achieve)

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args> friend vec<typename std::result_of<pow(Args&&...)>::type, N> apply(F&& f, const vec<Args, N>&||scalar<Args>::type... args) {
    vec<typename std::result_of<pow(Args&&...)>::type, N> r;
    for (int i= 0; i < N; i++) { r = f((is_vec<Args>?args.v[i]:args)...); }
    return r;
}
```

EDIT:

Based on Frank's comments I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
template<typename F, typename ...Args, size_t N>
vec<typename std::enable_if<sum<is_vec<Args,N>...>::value > 0, std::result_of<F&&(base_type<Args>::type&&...)>::type>::type, N>
(F&& f, Args&&...args) {
    vec<typename std::result_of<F&&(base_type<Args>::type&&...)>::type, N> result;
    for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i) { result.v[i] = f(extract_v(std::forward<Args>(args),i)...); }
    return result;
}
```

however I'm unsure if this version could even compile as it may be too ambiguous to be able to detriment the value of `N`.

Comment: If I'm reading this right (and I'm really not sure I am) I think you can acheive this using good-old partial template specialization? https://godbolt.org/g/DNMpq5 If that's corect, then I'll make a proper answer out of it.

Comment: not quite, I want to have any number of argument one being a least on being a vector of length N, and the others either a scalar or vector of length N, and then the function is apply using broadcasting to every element of the vectors, see last code block for C++/puedsocode of approximately what I want. I've considered partial specialization but how can that work with passing multiple arguments to a function, possibly using a tuple and std::apply from C++17, but I need a solution for C++14 so that wouldn't help any way.

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you mean, Something more along these general lines then? https://godbolt.org/g/uNPVFd (it's not 100% what you want, but I think it handles your main roadblock)

Comment: Yes, that seams about right, however, N should be passthru extract_v to insure the vectors are the same length, and the other problem is what if the second argument is the vector not the first which should be equally legal, is there some way to assert that any one of them be a vec type?

Comment: Specifically something that will produce a compile time error, preferably substitution failure, possibly something like `summation_template<is_vec<Args>::value...>::value >= 1`

Comment: I would also need to get the base types i.e. for `base_type<T>::type -> T=vec<U,N> type=U else type=T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want but...

It seems to me that can be useful a custom type traits to extract, from a list of types, the dimension of the `Vec`, iff (if and only if) in the list of types there is at least one `Vec` and there aren't `Vec`'s of different lengths.

I suggest something as follows, heavily based on template specialization,

```
template <std::size_t, typename ...>
struct dimVec;

// ground case for no Vecs: unimplemented for SFINAE failure !
template <>
struct dimVec<0U>;

// ground case with one or more Vecs: size fixed
template <std::size_t N>
struct dimVec<N> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>
 { };

// first Vec: size detected
template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct dimVec<0U, Vec<T, N>, Ts...> : public dimVec<N, Ts...>
 { };

// another Vec of same size: continue
template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct dimVec<N, Vec<T, N>, Ts...> : public dimVec<N, Ts...>
 { };

// another Vec of different size: unimplemented for SFINAE failure !
template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct dimVec<N1, Vec<T, N2>, Ts...>;

// a not-Vec type: continue
template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct dimVec<N, T, Ts...> : public dimVec<N, Ts...>
 { };
```

with the help of a template static variable

```
template <typename ... Args>
static constexpr auto dimVecV { dimVec<0U, Args...>::value };
```

Now should be easy.

You can write an `apply()` function that receive a variadic list of args of types `Args...` and is SFINAE enabled iff `dimVecV<Args...>` is defined

```
template <typename F, typename ... Args, std::size_t N = dimVecV<Args...>>
auto apply (F && f, Args ... as)
 { return applyH1(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, f, as...); }
```

Observe that the `N` variable is used to SFINAE enable/disable the function but is useful itself: it's used to pass a `std::index_sequence` from `0` to `N-1` to the first helper function `applyH1()`

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename F, typename ... Args>
auto applyH1 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &, F && f, Args ... as)
   -> Vec<decltype(applyH2<0U>(f, as...)), sizeof...(Is)>
 { return { applyH2<Is>(f, as...)... }; }
```

that initialize the returned `Vec` with single values calculated from the second helper function `applyH2()`

```
template <std::size_t I, typename F, typename ... Args>
auto applyH2 (F && f, Args ... as)
 { return f(extrV<I>(as)...); }
```

that uses a set of template functions `extrV()`

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto extrV (Vec<T, N> const & v)
 { return v[I]; }

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
constexpr auto extrV (T const & v)
 { return v; }
```

to extract the `I`-th element from a `Vec` or to pass-through a scalar value.

It's a little long but not particularly complicated.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Vec;

template <std::size_t, typename ...>
struct dimVec;

// ground case for no Vecs: unimplemented for SFINAE failure !
template <>
struct dimVec<0U>;

// ground case with one or more Vecs: size fixed
template <std::size_t N>
struct dimVec<N> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>
 { };

// first Vec: size detected
template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct dimVec<0U, Vec<T, N>, Ts...> : public dimVec<N, Ts...>
 { };

// another Vec of same size: continue
template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct dimVec<N, Vec<T, N>, Ts...> : public dimVec<N, Ts...>
 { };

// another Vec of different size: unimplemented for SFINAE failure !
template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct dimVec<N1, Vec<T, N2>, Ts...>;

// a not-Vec type: continue
template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct dimVec<N, T, Ts...> : public dimVec<N, Ts...>
 { };

template <typename ... Args>
static constexpr auto dimVecV { dimVec<0U, Args...>::value };

template <std::size_t I, typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto extrV (Vec<T, N> const & v)
 { return v[I]; }

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
constexpr auto extrV (T const & v)
 { return v; }

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Vec
 {
   private:
      std::array<T, N> d;

   public:
      template <typename ... Ts>
      Vec (Ts ... ts) : d{{ ts... }}
       { }

      T & operator[] (int i)
       { return d[i]; }

      T const & operator[] (int i) const
       { return d[i]; }
 };


template <std::size_t I, typename F, typename ... Args>
auto applyH2 (F && f, Args ... as)
 { return f(extrV<I>(as)...); }

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename F, typename ... Args>
auto applyH1 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &, F && f, Args ... as)
   -> Vec<decltype(applyH2<0U>(f, as...)), sizeof...(Is)>
 { return { applyH2<Is>(f, as...)... }; }

template <typename F, typename ... Args, std::size_t N = dimVecV<Args...>>
auto apply (F && f, Args ... as)
 { return applyH1(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, f, as...); }

long foo (int a, int b)
 { return a + b + 42; }

int main ()
 {
   Vec<int, 3U>  v3;
   Vec<int, 2U>  v2;

   auto r1 { apply(foo, v2, v2) };
   auto r2 { apply(foo, v3, v3) };
   auto r3 { apply(foo, v3, 0)  };

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(r1), Vec<long, 2U>>{}, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(r2), Vec<long, 3U>>{}, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(r3), Vec<long, 3U>>{}, "!" );

   // apply(foo, v2, v3); // compilation error
   // apply(foo, 1, 2);   // compilation error

 }
```

Comment: I've asked a follow on question about extending this solution to handle matrices as well as vectors, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322241/extending-multi-patterned-varadic-templates-in-c, are you able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want through a combination of partial template specialization and parameter pack extension.

```
#include <array>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using Vec = std::array<T, N>;

template<typename T>
struct extract {
  static auto exec(T const& v, std::size_t) {return v;}
  enum { size = 1 };
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct extract<Vec<T,N>> {
  static auto exec(Vec<T,N> const& v, std::size_t i) {return v[i];}
  enum {size = N};
};

template<typename T>
auto extract_v(T const& v, std::size_t i) {return extract<T>::exec(v, i);}

template<typename... args>
struct extract_size {
    enum {size = 1};
};

template<typename first, typename... rest>
struct extract_size<first, rest...> {
    enum {
        rest_size_ = extract_size<rest...>::size,
        self_size_ = extract<first>::size,
        size = rest_size_ > self_size_ ? rest_size_ : self_size_ 
    };

    static_assert(self_size_ == 1 || rest_size_ == 1 || rest_size_ == self_size_, "");
};

template<typename F, typename... args_t>
auto apply(F const& cb, args_t&&... args) {
  constexpr std::size_t size = extract_size<std::decay_t<args_t>...>::size;
  using result_t = decltype(cb(extract_v(std::forward<args_t>(args),0)...));

  Vec<result_t, size> result;

  for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {
    result[i] = cb(extract_v(std::forward<args_t>(args),i)...);
  }

  return result;
}
```